# WordPress, jQuery UI CSS Files?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, wordpress, jquery-ui-css-framework

I'm trying to create a WordPress plugin, and I would like to have jQuery UI Tabs in one of my settings pages.

I already have the scripting code set:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');                    // Enque jQuery
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');            // Enque jQuery UI Core
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');            // Enque jQuery UI Tabs
```

...and I have created the HTML and JavaScript too. Until here all are fine.

The question is:

The WordPress platform comes with some scripts already pre-installed like the one I have enqueue above. My script runs fine with the tabs, but it is not styled! So what I'm trying to ask, does the WordPress platform come with jQuery UI Theme pre-installed? ...and if so, how do I enqueue the style into my plugin?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Sounds more like you have an issue with finding an available styling within WordPress for the jquery-ui theme.

To answer your question. **No, WordPress has no useful styles available within the platform itself.** The only available css is in \wp-includes\jquery-ui-dialog.css, and that alone isn't very useful.

I also had the same issue, and I found **two options**. Either store it in a CSS folder and load it from there, or load it via **URL** (Google APIs). For JQuery UI I decided to rely on Google's CDA and added a way to utilize the 'Theme Roller'. Storing that amount of css code seems un-nessecary to begin with, and its too bad WordPress doesn't provide any styling support like they do with the jquery-ui scripts.

However, WP does offer scripts, which will keep the CSS up to date with `$wp_scripts->registered['jquery-ui-core']->ver`. You can either access it with `wp_scripts();` OR `global $wp_scripts;`.

Static-theme

```
$wp_scripts = wp_scripts();
wp_enqueue_style('plugin_name-admin-ui-css',
                'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/' . $wp_scripts->registered['jquery-ui-core']->ver . '/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css',
                false,
                PLUGIN_VERSION,
                false);
```

OR Dynamic-theme

```
$wp_scripts = wp_scripts();
wp_enqueue_style('plugin_name-admin-ui-css',
                'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/' . $wp_scripts->registered['jquery-ui-core']->ver . '/themes/' . $pluginOptions['jquery_ui_theme'] . '/jquery-ui.css',
                false,
                PLUGIN_VERSION,
                false);
```

And an example of locally storing it

```
wp_enqueue_style('plugin_name-admin-ui-css',
                plugins_url() . '/plugin-folder-name/includes/css/jquery-ui-theme-name.css',
                false,
                PLUGIN_VERSION,
                false);
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting CDA instead of cluttering up plugin with common stylesheets

Comment: Auto updating: `global $wp_scripts; wp_enqueue_style("jquery-ui-css", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/{$wp_scripts->registered['jquery-‌​ui-core']->ver}/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css");` the version is same as in WP (currently 1.10.3).

Comment: Actually, I only needed the dialog css. Use `wp_enqueue_style("wp-jquery-ui-dialog");`

Answer (score 6):

An update for the changes that has happened with WordPress ever since. Recent WordPress packages come with the CSS in the box.

You can find then in `wp-includes\css` and enqueue using `wp_enqueue_style()`.

I think for OP's use case `wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-jquery-ui-dialog' );` is all that was needed.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think a UI theme comes pre-installed. You need to add the script to the header.

I think you're looking for [this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). It allows you to add a script to your header. Just put the theme's css somewhere in your plugin folder and include that.

Comment: Can you also comment on is there a problem if multiple plugins starts to include separate jQuery UI themes? *Sigh* this half-hearted measure from WordPress team has made plugin developers to bundle own themes for jQuery UI, which is a mess and cross-plugin compatibility sucks. WP Team should: Embrace *one single theme*, and call it "WP jQuery UI theme", thats it, everyone should use it on their plugins. (Especially on admin!)

Comment: I'm pretty positive that Wordpress doesn't look at CSS conflicts. It's very common to "overwrite" your own stylesheet using another style so trying to search conflicts would be rather odd. Nonetheless I agree with you. Wordpress SHOULD improve this... Someone else could possibly help you with this. Try asking a new question. Good luck man!

Comment: @Ciantic, I know from experience that there can be a lot of issues with conflicting script/style includes between themes and plugins. One of the big ones I've seen is jQuery getting included as a direct link added to the header as opposed to the proper `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` method. There are some preventative measures you can take, but it's difficult to avoid. Unfortunately, even if you do it right, people will blame you for breaking their site if they add your plugin after already having a theme/plugin that does it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

To add some more details to EkoJr's answer, as of Jquery UI v1.11.4 if you add the whole JQuery UI CSS stylesheet, it might break the default Wordpress Theme styling.

So, you could only add the CSS classes corresponding to the slider component. Here are the classes I used (note : these are built for the **ui-darkness theme**) :

```
.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    /* this image is from the ui-darkness theme, use the one you'd like */
    background: #555555 url("img/jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_20_555555_1x400.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #eeeeee;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
    top: -.3em;
    margin-left: -.6em;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    cursor: default;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-bottom,
.ui-corner-right,
.ui-corner-br {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-bottom,
.ui-corner-left,
.ui-corner-bl {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-top,
.ui-corner-right,
.ui-corner-tr {
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-top,
.ui-corner-left,
.ui-corner-tl {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-bottom,
.ui-corner-right,
.ui-corner-br {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-bottom,
.ui-corner-left,
.ui-corner-bl {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-top,
.ui-corner-right,
.ui-corner-tr {
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-top,
.ui-corner-left,
.ui-corner-tl {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    /* this image is from the ui-darkness theme, use the one you'd like */
    background: #000000 url("img/jquery-ui/ui-bg_inset-soft_25_000000_1x100.png") 50% bottom repeat-x;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: .8em;
}
.ui-slider {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Also, please note that you can **prefix** those classes with your container ID. For exemple, if your slider has the ID 'slider', use :

```
 #slider .ui-state-default,
 #slider .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
 #slider .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    /* this image is from the ui-darkness theme, use the one you'd like */
    background: #555555 url("img/jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_20_555555_1x400.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #eeeeee;
}
....ETC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `wp_enqueue_style()` and `wp_enqueue_script()` calls correctly, and assuming other author's are using them correctly as well, then WordPress will take care of conflicts.

However if a plugin or theme author prints the styles or scripts directly to the head of the page using `wp_head` or `admin_head` actions then there's not much you can do to avoid conflict.

Refs:
 -  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style
 -  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: -1 for not answering OP's question. It wasn't how to add a generic style.

Comment: not very nice to our new members, hmm? the comment itself would have sufficed.

Answer (score 0):

I just face this issue and found the post then I found a way is that inserting class "subsubsub" to ul tag. The list will be not bad. The code will be:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul class="subsubsub"><li><a href="#tab1"></a></li>
<div id="tab1"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it can help someone.